# java letters in string a contains in string b

Tags: java, string, char, contains

Method:

```
public static boolean contains(String a, String b) { }
```

Input:

```
System.out.println(contains("ABBA", "BARAB"));
```

Output:

```
true
```

What I'm struggling at is how to properly check if String a contains in String b if there are more than 1 of the same char.

If this was public static boolen contains(char a, String b) {} 
this would have been 10 times easier. How do I go on to count that b has 2 or more A's and 2 or more B's?

input:

```
boolean c = contains("ABBA","AKROBAT");
```

output:

```
c = false
```

Comment: maybe you count them? do you have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: "f there are more than 1 of the same char." What do you mean by that? Please edit your question and add some more examples for how this method shall work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this approach:

- Note the difference in length between a and b
- For each letter in a...

  - Replace all occurrences of that letter in both strings with a blank
  - If the difference in length changes return false
- After the loop, return true

In code:

```
public static boolean contains(String a, String b) {
    int diff = a.length() - b.length();
    while (a.length() > 0) {
        b = b.replace(a.substring(0, 1), "");
        a = a.replace(a.substring(0, 1), "");
        if (diff != a.length() - b.length())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Not particularly efficient, but easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Ok now I got your point, You can go with this way

```
public static boolean contains(String a, String b) {
    boolean status = true;
    Map<String,Integer> mapA=new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,Integer> mapB=new HashMap<>();
    for(char i:a.toCharArray()){
        Integer val=mapA.get(""+i);
        if(val!=null){
            mapA.put(""+i,val+1);
        } else {
            mapA.put(""+i,1);
        }
    }
    for(char i:b.toCharArray()){
        Integer val=mapB.get(""+i);
        if(val!=null){
            mapB.put(""+i,val+1);
        } else {
            mapB.put(""+i,1);
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry:mapA.entrySet()){
        if (mapB.get(entry.getKey()) == null || entry.getValue() > 
                                                 mapB.get(entry.getKey())) {
            status = false;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

Now it will check both letter and same number of occurrence.

Eg 1:

```
System.out.println(contains("ABBA", "BARAB"));
```

Out put:

```
true
```

Eg 2:

```
System.out.println(contains("ABBA","AKROBAT"));
```

Out put:

```
false
```

Comment: Inside your loop return false if false - else return true after loop.

Comment: @JensKrogsboell comment not longer valid

Comment: @FlorentBayle yes. you are correct. I edited my answer. Thanks for point me out.

Comment: @FlorentBayle yeah me too.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the `a` string, remove the *first occurence* from `b` and check if `b` size changed with 1, if yes keep going, if no then return false:

```
public static boolean contains(String a, String b) {
    String temp = b;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        temp = temp.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(a.substring(i, i + 1)), "");
        if (b.length() - temp.length() != i + 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```